# How do I bring back the Spotify lock screen controls?

Tags: lock-screens

I accidentally permanently dismissed the play/pause/skip controls for the Spotify app on my lock screen. I've looked all over trying to find how to bring them back to no avail. How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting in the spotify app. From the spotify home page on your phone, open the settings (top right) and enable "Device Broadcast Status".

Comment: That didn't do it, thanks though. Still no controls after restarting app and phone, not that that should be necessary.